# using promise with angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

i use angular.js in front side.

in my controller.js i defined an init() method that will be called in

init of my controller.

Init method definition:

```
var init = function () {
$scope.callTeamsService();
if ($scope.teams.length == 0){
....
}else{
...
}
.....

};
```

in  **$scope.callTeamsService** i filled in **$scope.teams** variable.

**$scope.callTeamsService** method definition:

```
$scope.callTeamsService = function(){
        NavService.getTeams(function (response) {
                $timeout(function () {
                    $scope.teams = response;                        
                    }
                }, 200);
            });
    };
```

In my service.js i defined a **getTeams** method as follow:

```
service.getEquipes = function (callback) {
$http.get(urlBase+'users/' + $rootScope.globals.currentUser.loggedUser.idUser + '/teams')
                    .success(function (response) {
                        callback(response);
                    });
            };
```

My problem is when  **$scope.teams.length == 0** condition is reached the

**service.getEquipes** method in my service.js is not yet called.

How can i modify this code in order to finish the execution of **$scope.callTeamsService** method before reaching **$scope.teams.length == 0** condition.

Comment: Missing `'` here : `'/teams)`. Typo ?

Comment: `.then`, `.then` and `.then`

Comment: @gr3g where can i add the .then ?

Comment: .success -> .then. I wonder how your Service.js looks like

Comment: `var homeService = angular.module('Home', ['ngTable']); homeService.factory('NavService', ['$http', '$cookieStore', '$rootScope', '$timeout',
function ($http, $cookieStore, $rootScope, $timeout) 
{ var service {};
 ..........
 .........
service.getTeams = function (callback) {
$http.get(urlBase+'users/' + $rootScope.globals.currentUser.loggedUser.idUser + '/teams')
                    .success(function (response) {
                        callback(response);
                    });
            };
return service;
}
]);`

Comment: You really need to grasp how Angular works better - your code contains several anti-patterns with regard to the digest cycle. You're writing way too much code. This stuff is confusing at the start but once you get the hang of it it'll be a lot smoother :)

Answer (score 2):

```
  service/factory

   service.getEquipes = function () {
        return $http.get(urlBase+'users/' + $rootScope.globals.currentUser.loggedUser.idUser + '/teams');

        };


 // controller 
    var promise = NavService.getTeams.then (
           function(data) {
             //assign to $scope or do logic
           },
           function(err){
               console.log(err)
           } 
      )
```

Answer (score 2):

> How can i modify this code in order to finish the execution of `$scope.callTeamsService` method before reaching `$scope.teams.length == 0` condition.

That's the wrong way round - you need to *wait* with executing the `$scope.teams.length == 0` condition until the `$scope.callTeamsService` method has finished.

The classical method would be to give the `$scope.callTeamsService` method a callback parameter and call that in the timeout instead of `$scope.teams = response;`. Then you can put your condition in the `init` function in the callback that you pass.

However, you seem to want to use promises. For that, all of your functions (that all are asynchronous) should `return` a promise:

```
service.getEquipes = function (callback) {
    return $http.get(urlBase+'users/' + $rootScope.globals.currentUser.loggedUser.idUser + '/teams');
}
```

(that was easy, `$http` already returns promises)

```
$scope.callTeamsService = function() {
    return NavService.getTeams().then(function(teams) {
        return $timeout(function() {
            return teams;
        }, 200);
    });
};
```

(and [`$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) does as well - by invoking `then` and returning it from the callback you can chain them and get a new promise for both)

```
function init() {
    return $scope.callTeamsService().then(function(teams) {
        $scope.teams = teams;
        if (teams.length == 0) {
            …
        } else {
            …
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: The `$timeout` is likely there because OP did not really understand digests, I suspect you don't really need it there. It can just be return teams` which means it can just be `$scope.callTeamsService = NavService.getTeams`.

Comment: Hm, the 200 there looked like he wanted the timeout for some reason… Admittedly I don't know that much about `$scope` dealing with promises.

Comment: `then` handlers run in `evalAsync` which in turn triggers a digest on the scope anyway.